# Creating a snake game, when you press two directions quickly snake eats itself [Java]

Tags: java, user-interface

I hope this makes sense, but I'm trying to make a snake-type game in Java and if you press two directions at the same time/ too fast the snake goes on top of itself making you lose.
For example if you you're going downwards, and hit right then up very fast, you get the snake going straight up on the same column and killing itself, but it should go right one then up one. If anyone can help me that'd be great, thanks!

```
package tk.sketchistgames.Snake; 
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
        /**
         * Main graphical area for Snake
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 4085437479211945011L;

        private final int WIDTH = 600;
        private final int HEIGHT = 600;
        private final int DOT_SIZE = 10;
        private final int ALL_DOTS = 1200;
        private final int RAND_POS = 59;
        public static int DELAY = 90;


        private int x[] = new int[ALL_DOTS];
        private int y[] = new int[ALL_DOTS];

        private int dots, food_x, food_y, pdown_x, pdown_y, rdouble_x, rdouble_y, powerUp_x, powerUp_y, half_x, half_y;

        private boolean left = false;
        private boolean right = true;
        private boolean up = false;
        private boolean down = false;
        private boolean inGame = true;
        private int score = 0;
        private int fruitEaten = 0;
        private boolean Bonus = false;
        private boolean RDouble = false;
        private boolean bpower = false;
        private boolean halfpower = false;

        private Timer timer;
        private Image food;
        private Image head;
        private Image body;
        private Image pdown;
        private Image rdouble;
        private Image powerUp;
        private Image half;


        public Board() {
        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());

        setBackground(Color.decode("0x3F919E"));

        ImageIcon iid = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/body.png"));
        body = iid.getImage();

        ImageIcon iia = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/food.png"));
        food = iia.getImage();

        ImageIcon iih = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/head.png"));
        head = iih.getImage();

        ImageIcon iipd = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/pdown.png"));
        pdown = iipd.getImage();
        ImageIcon iird = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/pup2.png"));
        rdouble = iird.getImage();
        ImageIcon iipu1 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/pup1.png"));
        powerUp = iipu1.getImage();
        ImageIcon iihd = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/halfDown.png"));
        half = iihd.getImage();
        setFocusable(true);
        initGame();
    }


    public void initGame() {

        dots = 5;
        for (int z = 0; z < dots; z++) {
            x[z] = 50 - z*10;
            y[z] = 50;
        }

        locateFood();

        timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
        timer.start();
    }
    public void checkApple() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException {
        if ((x[0] == pdown_x) && (y[0] == pdown_y)){
                dots -= 1;
                score -= 50;
                AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Board.class.getResource("/sounds/powerdown.wav"));
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioIn);
            clip.start();
                bpower = false;
        }
        if ((x[0] == half_x) && (y[0] == half_y)){
                dots = dots /2;
                score = score /2;
                AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Board.class.getResource("/sounds/powerdown.wav"));
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioIn);
            clip.start();
            clip.start();
                halfpower = false;
        }
        if ((x[0] == powerUp_x) && (y[0] == powerUp_y)){
                dots += 4;
                score += 100;
                AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Board.class.getResource("/sounds/powerup1.wav"));
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioIn);
            clip.start();
                Bonus = false;
        }
        if ((x[0] == rdouble_x) && (y[0] == rdouble_y)){
                dots = dots * 2;
                score += 1000;
                AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Board.class.getResource("/sounds/powerup2.wav"));
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioIn);
            clip.start();
                RDouble = false;
        }
        if ((x[0] == food_x) && (y[0] == food_y)) {
            dots++;
            long r = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
            if(r == 4){
                locatePowerUp();
                Bonus = true;
            }
            long half = Math.round(Math.random() * 175);
            System.out.println(half);
            if(half == 89){
                locateHalfDown();
                halfpower = true;
            }
            long rdouble = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
            if(rdouble == 50){
                locateDoubleUp();
                RDouble = true;
            }
            long badpower = Math.round(Math.random() * 25);
            if(badpower == 25 || badpower == 20 || badpower == 15|| badpower == 10 || badpower == 5|| badpower == 0){
                locatePowerDown();
                bpower = true;
            }
            score += (50 + fruitEaten);
            AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Board.class.getResource("/sounds/eat.wav"));
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioIn);
            clip.start();
            fruitEaten++;
            locateFood();
        }
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        if (inGame) {
                if(halfpower){
                        g.drawImage(half, half_x, half_y, this);
                }
            if(Bonus){
                         g.drawImage(powerUp, powerUp_x, powerUp_y, this);

                }
            if(RDouble){
                g.drawImage(rdouble, rdouble_x, rdouble_y, this);
            }
            if(dots <= 0) gameOver(g);
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            Font small1 = new Font("arcadepix", Font.PLAIN, 20);

            g.setFont(small1);
            g.drawString("Score: " + score +  "  Food Eaten: " + fruitEaten + " Length: " + dots, 15, 15);

            g.drawImage(food, food_x, food_y, this);
            if(bpower){
                g.drawImage(pdown, pdown_x, pdown_y, this);
            }
            for (int z = 0; z < dots; z++) {
                if (z == 0)
                    g.drawImage(head, x[z], y[z], this);
                else g.drawImage(body, x[z], y[z], this);
            }
            if(Menu.pause){
                g.drawString("Paused! 'P' To unpause!", 20, 100);
                for (int z = 0; z < dots; z++) {
                    x[z] = 50 - z*10;
                    y[z] = 50;
                }
            }

            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
            g.dispose();

        }else{
                gameOver(g);
        }
        }


    public void gameOver(Graphics g) {
        if(dots >= 300){
                String msg = "You won!";
            Font small = new Font("arcadepix", Font.PLAIN, 20);
            FontMetrics metr = this.getFontMetrics(small);
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.setFont(small);
            g.drawString(msg, (WIDTH - metr.stringWidth(msg)) / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
            g.drawString("Total Score: " + score +"!", (WIDTH - metr.stringWidth(msg)) /2 - 12, (HEIGHT / 2) - 18);
            g.drawString("Total Food Eaten: " + dots + "!", (WIDTH - metr.stringWidth(msg)) /2 - 72, (HEIGHT / 2) - 38);
            g.drawString("Press Space to play again!", (WIDTH - metr.stringWidth(msg)) /2 - 77, (HEIGHT / 2) + 18);
            setBackground(Color.red);


        }else{
        String msg = "Game Over";
        Font small = new Font("arcadepix", Font.PLAIN, 20);
        FontMetrics metr = this.getFontMetrics(small);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.setFont(small);
        g.drawString(msg, (WIDTH - metr.stringWidth(msg)) / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
        g.drawString("Total Score: " + score, (WIDTH - metr.stringWidth(msg)) /2 - 12, (HEIGHT / 2) - 18);
        g.drawString("Press Space to Continue", (WIDTH - metr.stringWidth(msg)) /2 - 77, (HEIGHT / 2) + 18);
        setBackground(Color.decode("0x3F919E"));
    }
    }



    public void move() {

        for (int z = dots; z > 0; z--) {
            x[z] = x[(z - 1)];
            y[z] = y[(z - 1)];
        }

        if (left) {
            x[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
        }

        if (right) {
            x[0] += DOT_SIZE;
        }

        if (up) {
            y[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
        }

        if (down) {
            y[0] += DOT_SIZE;
        }
    }


    public void checkCollision() {

          for (int z = dots; z > 0; z--) {

              if ((z > 4) && (x[0] == x[z]) && (y[0] == y[z])) {
                  inGame = false;
              }
          }

        if (y[0] > HEIGHT) {
            inGame = false;
        }

        if (y[0] < 0) {
            inGame = false;
        }

        if (x[0] > WIDTH) {
            inGame = false;
        }

        if (x[0] < 0) {
            inGame = false;
        }
    }

    public void locateFood() {
        int r = (int) (Math.random() * RAND_POS);
        food_x = ((r * DOT_SIZE));
        r = (int) (Math.random() * RAND_POS);
        food_y = ((r * DOT_SIZE));
    }
    public void locatePowerDown() {
        int r = (int) (Math.random() * RAND_POS);
        pdown_x = ((r * DOT_SIZE));
        r = (int) (Math.random() * RAND_POS);
        pdown_y = ((r * DOT_SIZE));
    }
    public void locateDoubleUp() {
        int r = (int) (Math.random() * RAND_POS);
        rdouble_x= ((r * DOT_SIZE));
        r = (int) (Math.random() * RAND_POS);
        rdouble_y = ((r * DOT_SIZE));
    }
    public void locatePowerUp() {
        int r = (int) (Math.random() * RAND_POS);
        powerUp_x= ((r * DOT_SIZE));
        r = (int) (Math.random() * RAND_POS);
        powerUp_y = ((r * DOT_SIZE));
    }
    public void locateHalfDown() {
        int r = (int) (Math.random() * RAND_POS);
        half_x= ((r * DOT_SIZE));
        r = (int) (Math.random() * RAND_POS);
        half_y = ((r * DOT_SIZE));
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (inGame) {
                if(Menu.pause){

                }
            try {
                                checkApple();
                        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (LineUnavailableException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
            checkCollision();
            move();
                }

        repaint();
}


    public void reset(){
        left = false;
        right = true;
        up = false;
        down = false;
        inGame = true;
        score = 0;
        fruitEaten = 0;
        for (int z = 0; z < dots; z++) {
            x[z] = 50 - z*10;
            y[z] = 50;
        }
        dots = 5;
        bpower = false;
        locatePowerDown();
        RDouble = false;
        locateDoubleUp();
        locatePowerUp();
        locateFood();
        repaint();

    }
    private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
                if(inGame){
                        if(Menu.pause){
                                Menu.pause = false;
                        }else if(!Menu.pause){
                                Menu.pause = true;
                        }
                }
                if(!inGame){
                        reset();
                }
            }

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_P){
                if(Menu.pause){
                        Menu.pause = false;
                }else if(!Menu.pause){
                        Menu.pause = true;
                }
            }
            if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || key == KeyEvent.VK_A) && (!right)) {
                left = true;
                up = false;
                down = false;
            }

            if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT ||key == KeyEvent.VK_D) && (!left)) {
                right = true;
                up = false;
                down = false;
            }

            if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_UP || key == KeyEvent.VK_W) && (!down)) {
                up = true;
                right = false;
                left = false;
            }

            if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || key == KeyEvent.VK_S) && (!up)) {
                down = true;
                right = false;
                left = false;
            }
        }


                }
    }
```

Comment: Well first suggestion is to break up your methods a bit into more simple and easy to read methods. That will help narrow down your problem, and help us to more quickly help you out.

Comment: In your keypress function, you're checking to make sure that they don't press the opposite of the last key that was pressed - it would be better to check that they don't press the opposite of the direction the snake is actually moving.

Comment: BTW You shouldn't override `paint` in SwingComponents, `paintComponent` read this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your description, your code is changing the boolean variables before the move occurs. A simple solution would be to store all moves in a Queue, and process them by removing them, that way you ensure you won't overwrite a move.

In other words, every time you record a key event that would change the booleans, store some sort of signal (an int, a String, an enum, etc.) in a Queue, and in your move method, simply remove the signal from the front of the Queue and process it like you process the boolean variables. If you were to use an enum for UP DOWN RIGHT LEFT it would be fairly readable and you could use a switch-case to process each movement.

ex.

```
switch (movement) {
    case UP: /* up code */ break;
    case LEFT: /* left code */ break;
    case RIGHT: /* right code */ break;
    case DOWN: /* down code */ break;
}
```

where movement is the signal you removed from the queue, and UP DOWN RIGHT LEFT are enum's (for that matter they could be int constants, but as Bloch recommends in Effective Java, prefer enum types to int constants.)

```
private enum Movement { UP, DOWN, RIGHT, LEFT }
```

This allows you to refer to these types in the switch above, and instantiate the Queue as follows:

```
Queue<Movement> movementQueue = new ArrayDeque<Movement>();
```

Which in turn means you can add whichever movement you need simply by doing the following:

```
movementQueue.offer(UP); // or DOWN or RIGHT or LEFT, whichever you want.
```

And when you're ready to use them, access them as follows:

```
Movement movement = movementQueue.poll();
```

For more info on Queues: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html
For more info on enums: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Also because you said you're new to Java, I'd recommend Head First: Java for an overhead view, and Effective Java to learn a good amount of best practices.

Comment: You ninja you. I was hoping to post something about a queue too.

Comment: I don't want to ask you for code, because I wouldn't learn anything, but could you please help me a bit more? I am pretty new to Java, so I don't know too extremely much about it, like how would I use a Queue? Also when you commented "up code" or "left code" or "right code" or "down code" are you talking about the key code? I'm sorry if I'm asking too much but like I said earlier I'm still learning.

Comment: Not a problem at all, As for the "up code" etc, I meant you put the code for your movements in those directions -- up left right down -- where those comments are.

As for using Queues, i'll assume you've never seen one to be thorough. A Queue is a data structure where you add an element to the end, and you remove them from the front (sound familiar? it's more or less a waiting list.) In java, Queue is an interface, so you can use any of the classes that implement it. Specifically you really choose one of the following two (this will be broken into two comments.)

Comment: ArrayDeque  --  when you need an array internally.
LinkedList  --  when you want a linked list.

Generally you'll find that ArrayDeque is faster, so i'll use it here.

To use the queue, you just need an instance variable like the following

private Queue<Integer> movementQueue;

which you instantiate in your constructor to be the implementation you want, in this case,  movementQueue = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();

Then it's as simple as calling offer() to add a movement to the end, and poll() to remove one from the front.
To use enum type see the edit i'm about to put in my original post.

Comment: Okay, thanks for all the help but that didn't seem to work. It got rid of the problem, but it caused a new one too. It goes WAAAY too slow.

Comment: Would you mind updating the code you have so I can see the implementation?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31791/discussion-between-user2378526-and-ahlkanvorez)